# Can i eat chicken that's not halal?

Tags: halal-haram, quran, hadith, fiqh

Assalam u Alaikum,
      I am an exchange student  currently studying in the United States of America  for one year. Halal meat here is quite costly and my host family (the people who i live with) are Christian  and although they sometimes buy halal meat for me but still we don't have halal meat available  every week. My question is can i eat just chicken that's not halal?

Comment: Obviously you can not eat something that you know to be haram, that is what being haram implies.

Answer (score 2):

No you can't , you have to arrange Halal food for yourself . When you were going obviously you were aware about it .

In some cases when you are near to die , you can eat "Haram" for the sake of survival.

Answer (score -1):

What many people call "halal" and "zabiha" arent the same. Eating chicken, beef etc of people of the book is permissable per aya (verse) 5 of surah al maidah.
Some people say that that's only if people of the book follow their religous instructions when preparing the meat (like kosher), but from my research, even the most prominant and salafi sheikhs of saudi arabia have said it's ok to eat meat of people of the book, without the need to ask how they slaughtered it.

Comment: Claims should be supported with evidence. Christians also eat pigs, so by 5:5 should their pork be halal too? And if you make an exception for pork then by the same logic you should also make an exception for non zabiha carrion. If it is known that their meat is mostly not halal then it is not permissible to eat it, however if it is only a doubt\rumor then there may be no need to ascertain it.

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE! Please check out a [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) of our site to learn how this site works, and please cite sources and thoroughly answer the question asked.